# Login com Ionic e API PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, ionic, mobile

Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com Ionic v1 cuja API é em PHP/Mysql e agora preciso implementar um sistema de login. Conste que já tenho a plataforma funcionando da web, é uma rede social.

Como sou iniciante no Ionic, tenho "costurado" códigos garimpados... Nisso eu já consegui que o app carregue inicialmente a página "login" e, caso o nome e senha digitados estejam corretos, redirecione para a pagina "inicial" e grava um token no localStorage. A questão é que esse "nome e senha" é definido no código, preciso que seja consultado na API, dentre vários usuários já cadastrados...

Entre outras coisas, tenho o seguinte:

Controller

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
$scope.data = {};

$scope.login = function() {
    LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function(data) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Bem-vindo!'
            });

        $scope.gctoken = "id1";
        localStorage.setItem("gctoken", $scope.gctoken); // guarda o token

        $state.go('tabsController.inicial'); // redireciona
    }).error(function(data) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Erro!',
            template: 'Verifique os dados digitados!'
        });
    });
}
})
```

Service

```
.service('LoginService', function($q) {
return {
    loginUser: function(name, pw) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        if (name == '1' && pw == '2') {
            deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + name + '!');
        } else {
            deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
        }
        promise.success = function(fn) {
            promise.then(fn);
            return promise;
        }
        promise.error = function(fn) {
            promise.then(null, fn);
            return promise;
        }
        return promise;
    }
}
});
```

Routes (uma de suas linhas)

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

Inclusive pensei em colocar um if aí... algo como (somente a lógica):

```
if(status == 'logado'){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/inicial');
}else{
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
}
```

Preciso de um norte com códigos :)

Obrigado desde já.